# Searching for proper SE site or others forum for the < finding Arduino alternative for IRIG2 cable > question

Tags: discussion

I am trying to split my work to some small parts and ask some question about them o the Internet, for example I have tried to find some Arduino project for playing YouTube music on clubhouse form PC as you can see below:

[About playing YouTube audio from my computer into Clubhouse (hack and DIY) [closed]](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/86157/about-playing-youtube-audio-from-my-computer-into-clubhouse-hack-and-diy)

So I have asked it on t[he electronic SE site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/588933?noredirect=1) and [the lifehack SE site](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/25113?noredirect=1) and the [Arduino SE site](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/86157?noredirect=1), and it has been recognized as Off topic question!, now If possible I like to find out some alternative Forum like SE or other SE site to ask this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that this is not an open discussion forum. This is a question and answer site. You come with a specific problem and ask a specific question, and we answer it. Instead you seem to be asking general advice and "how to proceed" kind of questions that invite long-winded discussion.

Maybe the Arduino Project Discussion forum (https://forum.arduino.cc/c/projects/7) would be better for you.